# Retrying async function for 15 seconds on AWS Lambda

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, asynchronous

I'm fetching data from a website but the process sometimes fails so I make the function to retry it. But I'm using a 15 seconds timeout, so when the timeout is triggered it will stop retrying the function and it will return some error message from the website.

This works fine in my local machine but when I deploy my code to Vercel (running on AWS Lambda as far as I know), the setTimeout is being completely ignored, so the fetchData function keeps running until it gets the correct response or until the server default 60 seconds timeout triggers.

Here's the code:

```
router.get('/test', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const browser = await playwright.launchChromium({ 
        headless: false });
        const context = await browser.newContext();
        const page = await context.newPage();

        let timeout = false;

        let fetchDataTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
        timeout = true;
        }, 15000);

        const fetchData = async () => {
            await page.type('#code', '6824498040');
            let data = await (
                await Promise.all([
                    page.waitForResponse(
                        (response) =>
                            response.url() === `${env.API_URL2}` && response.status() === 200,
                        { timeout: 10000 },
                    ),
                    page.click('#btn-check'),
                ])
            )[0].json();
            if (data.errors && !timeout) {
                await page.reload();
                return await fetchData();
            } else {
                clearTimeout(fetchDataTimeout);
                return data;
            }
        };
        let data = await fetchData();
        await browser.close();

        res.json({
            status: 200,
            message: data,
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return res.status(500).send({ 'Server Error': `${error}` });
    }
});
```

I read that you have to wrap the setTimeout into a Promise and return it as an async function. Like this:

```
  const timeOut = async (t) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(`Completed in ${t}`)
    }, t)
  })
}

await timeOut(15000).then((result) => console.log(result))
```

But this will trigger the 15 seconds wait always. I need to discard the waiting if I get the correct response from fetchData and trigger the timeout if I don't 15 seconds after I start trying.

Any ideas???

Comment: use race() instead of all(), whihch wiats on the success and failt.

Comment: The website returns a 200 status code with the response, no matter if it's the data I need or the error message. Besides The fetchData function itself works fine as it is. I need to retry it for 15 seconds or discard the 15 seconds timeout if I get the correct response earlier.

Comment: you describe Promise.race(); the first one to resolve/fail wins. you could also put both promises in a wrapper promise which either inner one can complete.

Comment: Promise.all() on the page response and click looks like an issue.  This also doesn't really jive with lambda.  You have retry policies built in. My opinion, you should let it fail. Throw the failure into something like SQS and build a worker that does the retry.

Comment: "the first one to resolve/fail wins" That has NOTHING to do with what I need. The website returns data in 3 seconds tops but that data could be an error message. So I need to retry the operation, I insist RETRY the operation, for 15 seconds until I get the correct response. The timeout runs fine in my system but it's not running on the server, that's my problem.

Comment: my bad, misunderstood you. i got more coffee. in that case, use the 3rd promise wrapper i mentioned; you can re-do stuff in the workhorse middle promise until satisfaction is achieved, or the other middle promise times out. i would also un-nest some of the pyramid using named functions like done(), retry(), timesUp(), etc to make it a bit easier for fools like me to grok...

Comment: @zemaj This exact implementation without the setTimeout runs perfectly fine on a different website. Lambda has no problem with it. I insist on this: the fetchData function works fine because sometimes I get the correct response in 4 or 5 seconds. But if I don't  get the correct response, I want to retry the function for only 15 seconds and that's where my timeout is not running.

Comment: @lenny73 assuming fetchData is 'fine' because it works sometimes...you are basically trying to create a 'sleep' function in a lambda.  That is a bad design choice, but if you're okay with it then yes you need to wrap your timeout in a promise.  Refactor your code so that when it fails it calls your timeout promise (aka sleep) and does the retry X amount of times.

Comment: @zemaj. I know what sleep funcions are but this is nothing like that.

Comment: @dandavis You were right, man. Promise.race was the solution but wrapping the fetchData function and the setTimout with a Promise each first. So the one that resolves first will stop the entire process. I think this might work but I'm very tired right now. I'll try it tomorrow on the server, if it woks I'll post the solution here. Thanks.